# Can I use code from a computergame that is owned by a company A in order to develop my own game at company B?

Tags: licensing, patents

I want to develop a game with my own company, lets call it Indiantruckaimulator, that is very similiar to the already existing game, Eurotruck simulator. I would greatly benefit if I could use their Code/Software and simply add some changes.
Is there a way for me to get access to that code, preferably through colaboration :), to be able to build upon that?

Thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code is copyrighted

The code is copyrighted. You need a license from the copyright owner to manipulate it, if you alter it to the extent that you create a derivative work and do not qualify for Fair Use or a similar exception (see below).

Creating a game with a different map clearly is a derivative work.

You can only get that license from the company that initially made or currently distributes the game which code you want to use.

If they don't respond or don't want you to use their code, you can't use their code at all.

### But... fair use?!

There are **some** exceptions to needing a license, like fair use. However, those are generally not available for making a competing game.

Answer (score 3):

You ask permission, preferably with legal counsel to handle the details. It really is that simple.

Unsurprisingly, most companies don't want to give their code away- especially to a competitor. If you even get a response, they will expect something in return i.e. money.

Realistically though, it's unlikely they will respond, much less deal with you.